# flutter, Dart: The named parameter 'id' isn't defined

Tags: flutter, dart

I get this error for id, title, amount, and date.

The named parameter 'id' isn't defined.

here are the codes for the main.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './transaction.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'expense tracker',
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Transaction> transactions = [
    Transaction(
      id: 't1',
      title: 'New Shoes',
      amount: 69.99,
      date: DateTime.now(),
    ),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('expense tracker'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            child: Card(
              child: Text('CHART!'),
              elevation: 5,
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
          ),
          Column(
            children: transactions.map(
              (tx) {
                return Card(
                  child: Text(tx.title),);
              }).toList(),
            ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and the here is the code for transaction.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class Transaction {
  final String id;
  final String title;
  final double amount;
  final DateTime;
  Transaction(@required this.id, @required this.title, @required this.amount,
      @required this.DateTime);
}
```

please help me out.

4 positional arguments expected by 'Transaction.new', but 0 found.
Try adding the missing arguments.dart[not_enough_positional_arguments](https://dart.dev/diagnostics/not_enough_positional_arguments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax for `Transaction` is a bit off if you want named arguments, it should look like this:

```dart
class Transaction {
  final String id;
  final String title;
  final double amount;
  final DateTime;

  Transaction({
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
    required this.amount,
    required this.DateTime,
  });
}
```

Note that the arguments are wrapped in `{}` and that `required` isn't using the `@required` meta tag.

Comment: perfect. It's resolved. thanks buddy

Comment: @Toorajrezaei glad it worked, please press the checkmark underneath the score. That marks the answer as accepted. :)